# Consolidate multiple news/social streams into one (FB, Twitter, Flickr, RSS)

Tags: facebook, service, twitter, rss, stream

i am looking for a service to consolidate multiple streams from the web into one easy to use rss feed or something similar. i need at least support for facebook and twitter. ideally also for flickr, other rss feeds and more.

i've found http://feedstitch.com/ but they do not support FB.

thanks 
simon

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Join a Wallflux feed for FB with other feeds in Yahoo Pipes?

Comment: please explain little more with some reference / resource link.